# Android. Свой launcher. С чего начать?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Возникла необходимость сделать написанное приложение **launcher'ом**. Нужно, чтобы приложение запускалось с запуском android, и больше ничего было нельзя запустить. Подскажите, как это можно сделать.

Comment: это вирус чтоли такой?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю стоит начать с этого:
[android-launcher-plus](http://code.google.com/p/android-launcher-plus/)

Изучайте и делайте.

Comment: спасибо вам!

Answer (score 2):

Установите соответствующий интент фильтр в манифесте. Вот из доков:

> `CATEGORY_HOME`    The activity displays the home screen, the first screen the user sees when the device is turned on or when the *Home* button is pressed.

Как решить конфликт нескольких home'ов, думаю, сами разберетесь.

Comment: использовал это, только нашел чуть раньше, чем увидел ответ